# How to notify user when a certain value of a BLE device's characteristic changes on Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Would like to ask how will I get notified by the BLE device when it changes a specific characteristic value? For example, when Battery Level reaches 50%, I want to be notified that it reached specifically 50% and not every percentage move.

I want this to happen on the background obviously.

Thanks a lot.

UPDATE. This is my code to read the characteristic

```
override fun onCharacteristicRead(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic?, status: Int) {
        super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status)
        bluetoothGatt = gatt
        var charValue = characteristic?.value
        var decode = charValue?.toString(Charset.defaultCharset())
        Log.d("onCharacteristicRead", "Hits here: ${bluetoothGatt?.device} $decode ${charValue?.first()?.toInt()}")}
```

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: I only know how to read it but not to notify when it changes to whichever percentage I want

Comment: Please post the code

Comment: you can update the question

Comment: You must enable notifications as usual. When you get a notification, you need to check if the value is what you want, and only then continue. You can't request a specific percentage as trigger in the standard GATT battery service.

Comment: So for example, I want the 50% value of the battery service, I should listen for a value of "50"?